# Galois invariant line bundle and base change

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, schemes, line-bundles

Let $K$ be a number field and consider a finite Galois extension $L|K$. Moreover let $X$ be a projective, regular, integral variety over $K$. After a base change we obtain a morphism of varieties $f:X_L\to X$. Assume that $\mathcal L$ is a $\operatorname{Gal}(L|K)$ invariant line bundle on $X_L$; why is it true that there exists $n\in \mathbb N$ and a  line bundle $M$ on $X$ such that $\mathcal L^n\cong f^\ast M$? Clearly the Galois invariance here plays a crucial role, but I cannot figure out how to use it.

Many Thanks in advance

Comment: There is a "local-global" spectral sequence mapping the Picard group of $X$ to the Galois-invariant subgroup of the Picard group of $X_L$ with cokernel contained in the Brauer group of $K$.  Since every element of the Brauer group is torsion, it follows that every Galois-invariant element of the Picard group of $X_L$ descends after raising to an appropriately divisible tensor power. (There are also direct proofs, but the spectral sequence gives this and many other results as consequences.)

Comment: manifold, did you read Jason Starr's comment? It completely answers your question.

Comment: Yes, I would accept if it was an answer.

Comment: Yes, sorry. Noticed now

Comment: @manifold  You have nothing to apologize for.  I only posted my answer after the exchange between yourself and abx.  It is bad form, but I often just write comments rather than full answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am posting my comment as an answer.  This result is discussed in many sources.  I do not have Serre's "Galois cohomology" with me at this moment, but I am certain that it is discussed there.  It should be discussed also in "Dix exposes sur le Groupe de Brauer".

In fact the reference where I first learned this is Igor Dolgachev's textbook on invariant theory, Section 2 of Chapter 7.  He writes the long exact sequence of the spectral sequence in a slightly different setting of a group $G$ acting on $X_L$ through morphisms of $L$-schemes, rather than the "twisted" action of the Galois group of $L/K$ acting through morphisms of $K$-schemes.  However, the long exact sequence of the short exact sequence is the same in both cases.

$$
0\to \text{Pic}(X)\to \text{Pic}(X_L)^{\text{Aut}(L/K)} \to \text{Br}(K)
$$

Since the Brauer group of $K$ is a torsion group, every $\text{Aut}(L/K)$-invariant element of $\text{Pic}(X_L)$ is in the image of $\text{Pic}(X)$ after replacing the invertible sheaf by all sufficiently divisible tensor powers.